# Wordpress Paid Membership Pro not adding user to members list on checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, membership

I have been trying to configure a PMPro/Buddypress site for a few days now and I am having issues with PMPro. When I complete the checkout process the user gets added to the wp_users table, but is not added to the wp_pmpro_membership_users table, which means that a user does not have access to BuddyPress until their user level is updated manually by the admin user.

How can I have the user added automatically to the wp_pmpro_membership_users table upon successful signup?

Comment: If it's a paid plugin, your best bet would be to contact the plugin developer directly for support.

Comment: I don't think we can answer questions regarding paid WordPress modules because you are paying exactly for their support. Plus you should as questions regarding WordPress in the [StackExchange's WordPress](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize there was a specific Wordpress StackExchange.

Answer (score 0):

But to answer the question:

The payment/member workflow was failing because my local dev machine doesn't have SSL. The payment looked like it processing fine in Stripe, yet there was no indicator from the plugin (or elsewhere) that it was failing due to lack of SSL.

Once SSL was enabled, it worked as expected.